# Error Timeout on protractor test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

i'm aproaching the automation testing with protractor and jasmine. 
I'm doing a test on a registration page, with the code below:

```
               it('Verify Alert  message when New user registered itself for the first time',function() {
    FuncLib.ButtonClick('Close'); //Close the error message displayed in previous scenario
    Registration.Email.clear(); //Clear valid E-mail Id
    Registration.Password.clear(); //Clear Password
    Registration.ConfirmPassword.clear(); //Clear   Confirm Password 
    Registration.Firstname.clear(); //clear Firstname Password
    Registration.Lastname.clear(); //clear Lastname Password
    Registration.Phonenumber.clear(); //clear phonenumber
    browser.sleep(500);
    Registration.Email.sendKeys('Forfirmtestuser+user217@gmail.com'); //Enter valid E-mail Id
    Registration.Password.sendKeys('Hello1'); //Enter Password
    Registration.ConfirmPassword.sendKeys('Hello1'); //Enter wrong  Confirm Password 
    Registration.Firstname.sendKeys('candy'); //Enter Firstname Password
    Registration.Lastname.sendKeys('smith'); //Enter Lastname Password
    Registration.Phonenumber.sendKeys('9191919106'); //Enter phone number.
    expect(Registration.Checkbox.isPresent()).toBe(true); // Terms and condition checkbox should display
    Registration.Checkbox.click(); // select the Terms and condition checkbox
    Registration.Checkbox.click(); // select the Terms and condition checkbox
    browser.sleep(200);
        expect(Registration.RegisterButton.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        Registration.RegisterButton.click(); //click Register button
        browser.sleep(200);
            browser.driver.wait(function() {  // Wait for the current URL to change to Home page
                return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    return (/home/).test(url);
                });
            });


            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(Registration.HomeURL);
            console.log('When New user registered itself for the first time:');
                expect(Registration.AlertMsg.getText()).toEqual(Registration.msg6);
                Registration.AlertMsg.getText().then(function(text) {
                console.log(' When New user registered itself for the first time:');    //Jasmine expect statement : compare actual and expected value
                });
});
```

All works fine until this part of code:

```
                  expect(Registration.RegisterButton.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    Registration.RegisterButton.click(); //click Register button
    browser.sleep(200);
        browser.driver.wait(function() {  // Wait for the current URL to change to Home page
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                return (/home/).test(url);
            });
        });


        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(Registration.HomeURL);
        console.log('When New user registered itself for the first time:');
            expect(Registration.AlertMsg.getText()).toEqual(Registration.msg6);
            Registration.AlertMsg.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(' When New user registered itself for the first time:');    //Jasmine expect statement : compare actual and expected value
            });
```

here i get this error on the report at the end: 
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

And i don't really understand why.

Comment: Increase the 'defaultTimeoutInterval:60000' in your config.js file

Answer (score 1):

Firstly browser.sleep(200); is not good thing to use. Its always good to wait for an element to load. In protractor this can be done using the then function. Check the sample bellow, this will give you and idea

```
element(by.xpath("xpath_locator")).click().then(function(){
  var list = element(by.id('id_locator'));
  var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(until.presenceOf(list), 80000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
});
```

Comment: Ok this will help me but doesn't solve my problem. There's the possibility that it can't do two consecutives expect ?

Comment: i haven't tried the same. why dont you try it once. the code will remain mostly same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
1. Increasing default timeout in config file?
2. Increasing the seconds on sleep?
3. Inserting the expect inside the sleep?

```
expect(Registration.RegisterButton.isPresent()).toBe(true);
Registration.RegisterButton.click(); //click Register button
browser.sleep(2000).then(function() {  // Wait for the current URL to change to Home page
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        expect(url).toEqual(Registration.HomeURL);
        console.log('When New user registered itself for the first time:');
        expect(Registration.AlertMsg.getText()).toEqual(Registration.msg6);
        Registration.AlertMsg.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(' When New user registered itself for the first time:');    //Jasmine expect statement : compare actual and expected value
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jasmine Callbacks to assert asynchronous behavior. Jasmine test provides additional parameter as callback argument. Once you are done with the assertions you can invoke the callback API.

Example:

```
it('should have a button element present', function(done) {
browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

var gobtn = element(by.id('gobutton'));

gobtn.isPresent().then( (result) => {
 expect(result).toBe(true);    
 done();
 });    
});
```